# Python packages on Ubuntu server

Tags: python, ubuntu

For a project I want to get `httplib2`, `os`, `base64`, and `sys` on an `Ubuntu` server. I got `pip` on the server, but when I tried to download the packages/modules I get this.

```
Installing collected packages: httplib2
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission den                                        ied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2-0.11.3.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

ubuntu@ip-172-31-30-97:~$ pip install os
Collecting os
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement os (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for os
ubuntu@ip-172-31-30-97:~$ pip install base64
Collecting base64
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement base64 (from versions:                                         )
No matching distribution found for base64
ubuntu@ip-172-31-30-97:~$ pip install sys
Collecting sys
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sys (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for sys
```

I am also not sure if my python scripts will then be able to find the packages once they are downloaded onto the server. Maybe I am asking the wrong question, but my code needs these packages to run. Thanks!

Comment: Try, as the first error message says, installing with the `--user` option. Something like `pip install --user httplib2`.

Comment: Also, `os` and `sys` are built-in packages. Nothing to install there. And you have a typo in your line trying to install `base64`. Fix that and see what you get. You'll probably need the `--user` flag again.

Comment: Final thought: pretty sure these are all built in. Just type `import os` or `import sys` or whatever in your Python shell or at the top of your file and start using them.

Comment: Ok so it sounds like all of the packages are already there, but when I try to run my python script I get this error:  python sbd_fetch.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sbd_fetch.py", line 2, in <module>
    import httplib2
ImportError: No module named httplib2

Comment: At the top of my script I have all of my imports:
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2 
import os
import base64
import sys

Answer (score 0):

all the libs you are referring to are provided by default in python.

Answer (score -2):

```
$ pip install --user httplib2
```

The packages `base64`, `sys` and `os` are installed by default